# executeScript error in Vite React extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, vite

I am having an issue with the `executeScript` function with using Vite React chrome extension tools with [CRXJS](https://crxjs.dev/vite-plugin/)

I am receiving the error message "Uncaught (in promise) Error: could not get url" when trying to use it.

The initial injection of the `content.tsx` file from the `manifest.json` is working fine, but the error is occurring when I call `chrome.scripting.executeScript`.

my manifest.json

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "CRXJS React Vite Example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "action": { "default_popup": "index.html" },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["src/content.tsx"],
      "matches": ["*://*.github.com/*"]
    }
  ],
  "background": { "service_worker": "src/background.ts"},
  "permissions": ["webRequest", "webNavigation", "tabs", "activeTab", "scripting"],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["src/assets/*"],
      "matches": ["https://*/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my use of chrome.scripting in background.ts:

```js
const inject = (tabId) => {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
    if (tabs[0].url?.includes("some/search/string")) {
      const jsFiles = chrome.runtime.getManifest().content_scripts[0].js;
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
          target: { tabId },
          files: jsFiles,
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log("injected");
        });
    }
  });
};
```

I also tried with `files: ["content.tsx"]`, or `files: ["src/content.tsx"]`, but I received the error: "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not load file: 'src/content.tsx'" on chrome dev tools

The only way to not have `Could not load file error` is to put the bundled file name taken from `chrome.runtime.getManifest().content_scripts[0].js` ("src/content.tsx-loader.js")

Comment: The posted code is correct, so apparently the error is caused by something inside content.tsx or it's a bug in Chrome. BTW instead of reinjecting the content script maybe you could simply send a message to the already running script.

Comment: You may need to change `target: { tabId }` to `target: { tabId: tabs[0].id }`. Please also post where you are calling inject.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto the tabId doesn't solve my issue
I call inject in chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener

Comment: @wOxxOm my goal is really to reinject code on page event, but I'm stuck with this executeScript function who doesn't work

Comment: Please disclose how to get the tabId of the inject argument.

Comment: It seems my issue is related to the react injection himself. The first injection of react code in my page work well, but when an event is trigger on the page (in my case it's on description update on github pull request page), the re-injection of the react code doesn't work.